# Need an Excel cell to turn red 5 days after a date is entered into another cell

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am working on a log that has to have a cell turn a certain color five days after the date that is entered into another cell.

For example, there is a "Date Received" column (Cell H15) where there is a date entered when we received the purchase order. Five days after the date entered in cell H15, I need column (Cell L15) to turn red.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "conditional formatting".

Answer (score 1):

Try Conditional Formatting with a formula such as:

```
=TODAY()-H15>5
```

with formatting of your choice, applied to a suitable range.

Comment: opps, this should be enough :D i'll remove mine :D